# Urban Airship Xamarin Native for iOS. Issue with Custom event properties

Tags: ios, xamarin, urbanairship.com

I'm implementing Urban Airship into my `Xamarin` Native app and currently stuck at implementing Custom event property. The property does not get registered in the server, the event value and event name does get registered tough. Here is how I implement the Custom event:

```
    UACustomEvent customevent = new UACustomEvent ();
    customevent.EventName = "Startup";
    customevent.EventValue = new NSDecimalNumber ("1.0");
    customevent.SetStringProperty (App.Instance.Settings.AppVersion, "AppVersion");
    customevent.SetStringProperty ("Debug", "RunMode");
    customevent.Track ();
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

ps: I have registered the event property in the dashboard.

Comment: Hi Michael, welcome to StackOverflow! Please paste you code instead of adding an image

Comment: Noted! thanks Nick.